# How can I get gedit to compile pdf on mac

Tags: compiling, mactex, gedit

I just got a macbook air (the version right before the current one) and I have MacTex installed and I have the latex plugin for gedit. How can I get gedit to compile pdf for me? Before on ubuntu I just hit ctrl + alt + 1 and it worked but nothing is happening now.

Though, I can use texshop but I prefer gedit due to the black background.

Comment: Do you have `rubber` installed? The latex gedit plugin relies on it to compile documents AFAIK.

Comment: [TeXshop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34521/15717) for those interested

Comment: You can install `rubber` with [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew). But I suggest switching to a different editor/front end such as Aquamacs or TeXShop.

Comment: Dear @egreg, I'm fine with using texshop, the only thing is the white background and my high powered glasses make it unpleasant to type things over a long period of time. How can I change the backgound color in texshop to black; or dark blue as I had on my old gedit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background color of TeXShop can easily be changed in the preferences. Just select *TexShop->Preferences...* from the menu and look for *Background Color* in the *Source* tab:

[image]

Comment: How do I change the latex highlight color?

Comment: Here's a nice example of how to change everything. [Change default color scheme to something else in TexShop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/97648)